# how can i change item state from ready to Delivering?

Tags: google-ad-manager

how can i change item state from ready to Delivering?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status of a line item can not be amended manually, it is determined by Ad Manager. Status is updated automatically. 
A 'ready' line item concerns line items that will start later or just got activated. 
The 'delivering' status concerns line items that started to deliver allready.

[Here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/82991?hl=en) are the detailed status Ad Manager handles.

Comment: Is your start date past? If yes, something in your set up might prevent line item to start delivering..